# Show button below soft keyboard

Tags: android

I need to show a button below (numeric) soft keyboard in a layout of an android app. I don't need to use "done" key in the keyboard, but the button below the soft keyboard which is keyboard width-wise.

Comment: explain more or provide screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question. But if you would like to show your own button below the keyboard, this is not possible. You can't change the position of the system keyboard. If your requirements are simple enough, you might want to consider building your own numeric keyboard in the layout and not using the system keyboard. This is not ideal, but then you would be able to add a button below the keyboard

Comment: O.K. Then i need to build custom keyboard. Thx.

Comment: Sure. If this answers your question, can you please mark it as the answer. Also if you need any help with the custom keyboard, let me know!